# How best to overcome USB 3.x cable length limit?

Tags: usb, video-capture

My boss recently gifted me an Elgato HD60 S capture card that he was not using.  I plan to use it to stream Nintendo Switch and/or Wii games to Twitch; I cite these two consoles because I would be using real hardware to do so, and none the other consoles owned by me & my wife currently have HDMI output.  The computer that will receive the captured footage is a 2009 Mac Pro (henceforth abbreviated to MP) with—hopefully—sufficient power to stream to Twitch at a consistent 60fps (its GPU is an MSI Armor RX 580 with 8GB of VRAM).  I already have a couple Sonnet USB 3.x PCIe cards in mind, so this problem is effectively solved.

The issue I am trying to solve—and the reason I am posting here—is one of physical distance.  My consoles and my MP are on opposite sides of the room; there is a sliding glass door that goes out to our patio between my desk with my MP and our TV & consoles.  I do have my MP connected to our TV via a 25’ HDMI cable (and I am using all twenty-five feet of that length) that I’ve run above this door, so I can use it as a third monitor…but all the Googling I have done tells me that the maximum USB cable length falls well short of that distance.  Moving our consoles or my desk & MP isn’t an option, as I do not want to upset my wife.  Running another 25’ HDMI cable from the capture card at my MP to our consoles & TV would remove my ability to stream Wii games from real hardware, as the Wii’s HDMI cable ends in the Wii-specific proprietary A/V plug.  Furthermore, the capture card in question appears to get power from the USB-C port on the device itself, as there is no battery or external power jack on the unit, so any solution to extend a USB run length must also include sufficient power transmission.

Rather tricky problem to solve, isn’t it?  I would greatly appreciate suggestions & advice on how to solve this in a way that lets me stream and also keeps my wife happy with the arrangement of our living room.

Answer (score 0):

There are **active** (powered) USB 3.2 extension cables that claim to be able to extend by 33 feet and maintain 5Gb/s speeds. For example: [Tripp-Lite](https://tripplite.eaton.com/usb-3-2-gen-1-active-cable-aluminum-10-m-33-ft%7EU33010MAL).

Note: I have not actually used these and have no direct experience.

Comment: Good Lord, those are pricey…  I hope I have other options.

Comment: @AeternaGM - Using active optical USB cables is your only option at those lengths you require. **You likely will also need an optical HDMI cable.**

Comment: @AeternaGM, see https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb+repeater+cable